# Presto Window Function - (sum over partition by)

Tags: sql, sum, window, presto

I have the following Presto 2 tables, one storing budget information by client & day, and the other one storing spend information by client & day

```
select day, client_id, budget_id, budget_period, budget_amount
from budget_table
```

| day | client_id | budget_id | budget_period | budget_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-27 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 |
| 2021-02-28 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 |
| 2021-03-02 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 |
| 2021-03-06 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 |
| 2021-02-28 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 |
| 2021-03-02 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 |
| 2021-03-03 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 |
| 2021-03-04 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 |
| 2021-03-05 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 |

```
select day, client_id, spend
from spend_table
```

| day | client_id | spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-27 | 1 | 8 |
| 2021-02-28 | 1 | 9 |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-03-02 | 1 | 7 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 | 6 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | 16 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 | 19 |
| 2021-03-06 | 1 | 18 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2 | 13 |
| 2021-02-28 | 2 | 15 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2 | 14 |
| 2021-03-02 | 2 | 15 |
| 2021-03-03 | 2 | 20 |
| 2021-03-04 | 2 | 25 |
| 2021-03-05 | 2 | 18 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2 | 27 |

Below is desired output:

| day | client_id | budget_id | budget_period | budget_amount | spend | spend_over_period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-27 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 8 | 8 |
| 2021-02-28 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 9 | 9 |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-03-02 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 7 | 7 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 | 16 | 16 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 | 19 | 35 |
| 2021-03-06 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 | 18 | 53 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 13 | 13 |
| 2021-02-28 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 15 | 28 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 14 | 14 |
| 2021-03-02 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 15 | 29 |
| 2021-03-03 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021-03-04 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 25 | 45 |
| 2021-03-05 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 18 | 63 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 27 | 90 |

I have tried

```
select s.day, 
       s.client_id, 
       b.budget_id, 
       b.budget_period, 
       b.budget_amount,
       s.spend,
       case when b.budget_period = 'daily' then s.spend
            when b.budget_period = 'monthly' then sum(s.spend) over (partition by b.budget_id, month(date(s.day))) 
            when as spend_over_period = 'one_time' then sum(s.spend) over (partition by b.budget_id)
       end as budget_over_period
from spend_table as s
    join budget_table as b
        on s.day = b.day
        and s.client_id = b.client_id 
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

But, I get u'EXPRESSION_NOT_AGGREGATE' error.
Does anybody know how to query to get the desired output in Presto?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `group by` clause completely and use ordering and frame for your window functions with `order by date(s.day)` and `range between unbounded preceding and current row`:

```sql
select s.day,
       s.client_id,
       b.budget_id,
       b.budget_period,
       b.budget_amount,
       s.spend,
       case
           when b.budget_period = 'daily' then s.spend
           when b.budget_period = 'monthly' then sum(s.spend) over (partition by b.budget_id, month(date(s.day)) order by date(s.day) range between unbounded preceding and current row)
           when b.budget_period = 'one_time' then sum(s.spend) over (partition by b.budget_id order by date(s.day) range between unbounded preceding and current row)
       end as spend_over_period
from spend_table as s
    join budget_table as b
on s.day = b.day
    and s.client_id = b.client_id
order by 2,3,1
```

Output:

| day | client_id | budget_id | budget_period | budget_amount | spend | spend_over_period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-27 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 8 | 8 |
| 2021-02-28 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 9 | 9 |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-03-02 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 7 | 7 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 | 1-1 | daily | 10 | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 | 16 | 16 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 | 19 | 35 |
| 2021-03-06 | 1 | 1-2 | monthly | 500 | 18 | 53 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 13 | 13 |
| 2021-02-28 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 15 | 28 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 14 | 14 |
| 2021-03-02 | 2 | 2-1 | monthly | 400 | 15 | 29 |
| 2021-03-03 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021-03-04 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 25 | 45 |
| 2021-03-05 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 18 | 63 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2 | 2-2 | one_time | 1000 | 27 | 90 |